# LDAP Active Directory Login via MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I am having real troubles verifying the user.

There are two scenarios for who is logging in:

- User is registered on the domain.
- User is an external client.

And two scenarios for access:

- User is on the domain
- User is on an external PC.

So what I am hoping to do is:

1. grab the users windows login, and attempt login via LDAP verification.
2. If this fails, they are either not registered on domain, or not on a domain PC. So a form would come up to type in info.
3. The form would then check against LDAP (registered user), else against the sites DB (external user).

Ive tried a few guides, and an intranet application. All that is doing is throwing my username onto screen. Regardless of anything. I have no idea how to verify it aagainst anything as I cant find ANY code relating to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to configure your site to implement both Windows authentication and Forms authentication.

You should deploy your application twice.

1. Once for AD authorization which will pass through if your user is logged on.
2. The other for form authentication and provide a login box.

Be sure to set the corresponding authorization options in your IIS manager.

You can choose to only implement forms authentication.  And then choose to use a membership provider that verifies your credentials to AD. But a pass-trough option using the loggedon user from that pc would not be very secure

Comment: Can you please explain why it would not be very secure? Assume SSL is used.

Comment: If i check for pass-trough authentication with my ldap if the user trying to connect is know in MyDomain\user. And he adds his own computer to a domain of himself so he will also have the name 'MyDomain\user' but in fact is not in my domain but his own. Still he could get verified. You won't pass through real AD verification but just checking a username with LDAP.

Comment: I thought LDAP checked against the passwords too? So if the user is the same, he would still have to know the password (or have the same password)

Comment: ytes but then you cannot use pass-trough authentication and you will still have to show a login messagebox